# sql in() function on case statement

Tags: sql, function, case, notin

the code below is not working for me and I would like help with a work around if possible.

I'm trying to exclude certain elements in based on dates but I'm having no luck.

My code so far looks somewhat like this:

```
SELECT CASE  
WHEN date > '2013'  
       THEN element NOT IN ('e1', 'e2', 'e3') --exclude 3 elements  
       WHEN date > '2012' AND date <= '2013'  
       THEN element NOT IN ('e2', 'e3') --exclude 2 elements  
       WHEN date > '2011' AND date <= '2012'  
       THEN element NOT IN ('e3') --exclude 1 element  
       WHEN date <= '2011'  
       THEN element -- no elements excluded  
       END  
FROM elementTable
```

This is pseudo code. The error given by sql is 'incorrect syntax on NOT'.
I'm not completely sure why, but it doesn't seem to like my NOT IN declaration.

Any sort of tip, hint or help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what sql are you using? MSSQL or mysql

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN [DATE] > '2013' AND element NOT IN ('e1', 'e2', 'e3')
   THEN element 
   WHEN date > '2012' AND date <= '2013' AND element NOT IN ('e2', 'e3') --exclude 2 elements
   THEN element 
   WHEN date > '2011' AND date <= '2012' AND element NOT IN ('e3') --exclude 1 element
   THEN element 
   WHEN date <= '2011'
   THEN element -- no elements excluded
   ELSE
    NULL
   END
FROM elementTable
```

Comment: Worth to note, that in this solution you still get NULLs for excluded elements.

Comment: true. He/She will have to define else section to what he/she wants to do. pseudo code do not mention anything about else so i put NULL for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add expression in `THEN` section of `CASE` while statement is expected.
Instead of using `CASE` try to move conditions to `WHERE` section:

```
SELECT element
FROM elementTable
WHERE (date > '2013' AND element NOT IN ('e1', 'e2', 'e3'))
OR (date > '2012' AND date <= '2013' AND element NOT IN ('e2', 'e3'))
OR (date > '2011' AND date <= '2012' AND element NOT IN ('e3'))
OR date <= '2011'
```